# OP07 unity-gain stability

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, gain

Is the OP07 unity-gain stable? I am powering it with a +/- 5V supply. I am using it to buffer a DC signal which varies slowly.

Most of the modern op-amps have their datasheets mentioning them explicitly as unity-gain stable, but nothing like this is mentioned in the [OP07 datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/OP07.pdf).

Comment: it have already used as a voltage follower, so the answer is yes it does. From a application note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is unity gain stable. Figure 18 shows the curve for 0 dB of closed-loop gain vs frequency.

[image: Closed-loop gain vs frequency]

An interpretation of this diagram: The vertical axis is in dB. For example, for a closed-loop gain of 0 dB (or 20 dB, or any other gain in the diagram), the opamp is not unstable at any frequency. The curves just tell you that the closed-loop gains (for those gain settings) roll off / decay like that, with frequency. The higher the gain, the lower the bandwidth, so that the product gain*bandwidth is constant. It may be assumed that it is stable for G=1 (0 dB) because the datasheet specifies the behavior for that gain (it shows the curve for it). If it was unstable for G=1, you wouldn't see a curve for it, in that figure.

Comment: Does this mean eg. the opamp becomes unstable at a gain of 20,above30kHz ?

Comment: @EmbSysDev The vertical axis is in dB. And no, for a closed-loop gain of 20 dB, the opamp is not unstable at any frequency. The curves just tell you that the closed-loop gains (for those gain settings) roll off / decay like that, with frequency. The higher the gain, the lower the bandwidth, so that the product gain*bandwidth is constant. I said it is stable for G=1 (0 dB) because the datasheet specifies the behavior for that gain (it shows the curve for it). If it was unstable for G=1, you wouldn't see a curve for it, in that figure.

Answer (score -1):

OP07 is so slow that it would be surprising - to say the least - if it was not unity gain stable. I wonder if there are any IC op—amps whatsoever with similarly low-end AC specs that are *not* unity gain stable. If anyone knows of such, please comment! I’m ready to be surprised.